# Relation between two models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, one-to-many

It seems like a trivial question but I am new to Django. I have two models user and competition.

The user can create and join one or many competition.
How to specify this relation as the user can be the owner of competition/s and can be a participant in one or more competition.

Answer (score 1):

I Assume You have two tables `User` and `Competition`:

then in competition you can user `models.ManyToManyField`

Example

```
class User:
   ...

class Competition:
   ...
   creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
   participents = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: Great thank you! Is there a reason why the many to many is in the competition model as I know the many to many relation can be in any of the two model, right?

Comment: Yes, `ManyToMany` field can be in either of the models, I just put it in `Competition` model assuming your `User` model is default model from django. You can tick the checkmart if this solved your issue. Thanks.